# Angular using pipes and index in ngFor

Tags: angular

Angular had many changes in the beta, my issue is that try to use  pipes and the index in a ngFor and i get this message:

`Parser Error: Unexpected token =`  and

```
The pipe 'let' could not be found
```

when i use this code:

```
 <div style="overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 200px;">
        <div (click)="showComentario(index);" *ngFor="let comment of comentarios| filterSource:selectedSource | let index=index; ">
            {{comment.comment}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

if i change the order like this:

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 200px;">
    <div (click)="showComentario(index);" *ngFor="let comment of comentarios;let index=index;| filterSource:selectedSource |  ">
        {{comment.comment}}
    </div>
</div>
```

i get this message:

```
Template parse errors:
TypeError: key[0] is undefined  



Parser Error: Unexpected token |, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 47 in [let comment of comentarios; let index=index;
```

How i can use pipes and index at the same time?

**EDIT:**
I modified the code as the comments suggested like this:

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 200px;">
    <div (click)="showComentario(index);" *ngFor="let comment of comentarios | filterSource:selectedSource;let index=index ">
        {{comment.comment}}
    </div>
</div>
```

i keep getting these errors:
`TypeError: key[0] is undefined` and `Parser Error: Unexpected token |`

Comment: remove the `| ` pipe from end of `ngFor` expression..

Comment: yes, and replace it with a semicolon. `let x of y | zzz; let index=index`

Comment: @dbandstra changed the code, still getting the same errors =/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try below,

```
<div (click)="showComentario(i)" *ngFor="let comment of comentarios | filterSource : selectedSource; index as i" >
  {{comment.comment}}
</div>
```

Hope this helps!!